# Como posso conferir se existem numeros iguais na mesma coluna ou linha em uma matriz numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

```
from random import sample
import numpy as np

a = sample(range(1, 5), 4)
b = sample(range(1, 5), 4)
c = sample(range(1, 5), 4)
d = sample(range(1, 5), 4)

jogo = np.array([[a[0], a[1], b[1], b[2]],
                [a[2], a[3], b[2], b[3]],
                [c[0], c[1], d[0], d[1]],
                [c[2], c[3], d[2], d[3]]])
```

caso existam numeros iguais na mesma linha ou na mesma coluna, preciso embaralhar os sample para atualizar a array ate que não existam valores iguais por linha e coluna.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o método nunique() do pandas para te retornar quantas entradas únicas tem em cada linha ou coluna. Se tiver 4 entradas únicas, é porque os valores são todos diferentes. Em seguida, use o método all() do numpy para verificar se todas as linhas/colunas tem 4 entradas únicas.

Para verificar se todas as colunas tem somente entradas únicas:

```
import pandas as pd
valores_unicos = [pd.Series(jogo[:,coluna]).nunique() for coluna in range(4)]
todas_colunas_sem_repeticao = (np.array(valores_unicos) == 4).all()
todas_colunas_sem_repeticao
```

Para verificar se todas as colunas tem somente entradas únicas:

```
import pandas as pd
valores_unicos = [pd.Series(jogo[:,linha]).nunique() for linha in range(4)]
todas_colunas_sem_repeticao = (np.array(valores_unicos) == 4).all()
todas_linhas_sem_repeticao
```

Ambos os códigos vão retornar um booleano (*True* caso todas linhas/colunas tenha somente valores únicos ou *False* caso contrário). Se o resultado for *False*, sorteie novamente.